# Safe/reliable/standard process for making major changes to a database with existing data?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, schema

I would like to take one table that is heavy with flags and fields, and break it into smaller tables.  The parent table to be revised/broken down already contains live data that must be handled with care.

Here is my plan of attack, that I'm hoping to execute this weekend while no one is using the systsem.

1. Create the new tables that we will need
2. Rename the existing parent table, ParentTable, to ParentTableOLD
3. Create a new table called ParentTable with the unneeded fields gone, and new fields added
4. Run a procedure to copy the entries in ParentTableOLD to the new tables, mapping old data to new tables/fields where applicable
5. Delete the ParentTableOLD table

The above seems pretty reasonable and simple to me, I'm fairly certain it will work.  I'm interested in other techniques to achieve this (the above is the only thing I can think of), as well as any kind of tools to help stay organized.  Right now I'm running on pen and paper.

Reason I ask is that several times now, I've been re-inventing the wheel just because I didn't know any better, and someone more experienced came along and saw what I was doing and said, "oh there's a built-in way to help do this," or, "there's a simpler way to do this."  I did coding for months and months with Visual Studio before someone stopped by and said "you know about breakpoints to step through the code, yeah?" --- life changing, hah.

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 with SSMS.

Comment: Make a backup of the old database first, in case something goes wrong.

Comment: Oh for sure, yeah.  I have a process that runs nightly that makes a full backup.

Answer (score 1):

A good trick to assist you in creating your '_old' tables is:

```
SELECT  *
INTO    mytable_old
FROM    mytable
```

SELECT INTO will copy all of the data *and* create your table for you in one step.

This said - I would actually retain the current table names and instead copy everything into another schema. This will make adapting queries and reports to run over the old schema (where needed) a lot easier then having to add '_old' to all the names (since instead you can just find/replace the schema names).

Answer (score 0):

If at all possible, I'd be doing this is some sort of test environment first and foremost. If you have external applications that rely on the database, then make sure they all run against your modified structure without any hiccups.

Also do a search on your database objects that might reference the table you are going to rename. For example;

```
SELECT Name
FROM sys.procedures
WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%MyTable%'
```

Try and ensure some sort of functional equivalence from queries between your new and old schemas. Have some query/queries that can be run against your renamed table and then have your reworked schema referencing your new table structure. This way you can make sure the data returned is the same for both structures. If possible, prepare these all ahead of time so that it is simply a series of checks you can do once you've done your modifications and if there are differences, this can help you decide whether you proceed with the change or back it out.

Lastly, have a plan for working out how you could revert to the old schema if something catastrophic were to occur. If you'd been working with your new table structure for a period of time, and then discovered a major issue, could you revert back to the old table and successfully get the data out of your modified table structure back to the old table? Basically, just be a follow the boy scout rules and **be prepared**.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer for your overall problem, but a couple tools that you might find useful for your Step 4 is RedGate's [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) and [Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/). SQL Compare will perform schema migrations, and Data Compare will help migrate data. You can move data to new columns and new tables, populate default values, sync from dev to production, among other things.

You can make your changes in a dev environment with production data, and when you're satisfied with the process, do the actual migration in production.

Answer (score -1):

Make a backup of database (for reference : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187510.aspx) and then you can do the required steps. If everything goes fine, then go ahead else restore the old database ( for reference  : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177429.aspx)
You can even automate this process of making a backup for say, every week.

Comment: This particular answer was already addressed in the comments and to be honest is fairly common sense

Comment: @Michael : before making any claims you should see the time when I posted the solution. Both the comment and my post are of the same time frame. So it might be possible that we both might be writing at the same time. So think before you point a finger on some one.

Comment: There were at least five minutes between the two - I don't see this answer taking five minutes. Besides, once posted and you saw the comments why wouldn't you delete your answer? This really isn't a good excuse.

edit: Also, for the record, downvote isn't from me.

Comment: I am not talking of the down vote, I am talking of the comment. And I dint checked the comment, that is why the post was not deleted. Further, it takes time to find the exact reference for the question. And I dont think I owe any excuse to you.